# Помогите написать алгоритм для машины Тьюринга

Tags: алгоритм

Необходимо написать МТ, выясняющую, является ли введённый x кубом некоторого натурального числа. Алфавит состоит из пустого регистра и 1.
Число x кодируется как последовательность из x+1 единичек, идущих подряд. 
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Идея алгоритма состоит в том, что сначала удаляется одна единичка с конца введенного числа (т.е, чтобы осталось ровно x единичек). После этого головка перемещается в последний пустой регистр перед единичками. Все это делается легко, здесь проблем нет.

Затем машина переходит в состояние q2.0.1(первая цифра - основание куба, вторая - сколько раз мы число сложили само с собой, 3 - степень), делает 2 шага вправо и в q2.1.2, 2 шага вправо и в q2.2.3, Еще . Если машина видит пустую ячейку, а слева от неё единичка, то, очевидно, это куб двойки. Если нет, то в q3.0.0, 3 шага вправо, q3.1.0, 3 вправо ... в q3.3.1. ... 3.3.3 Та же проверка.

Все это происходит до тех пор, пока машина после перехода в qn.n.3 не увидит пустую ячейку.

Если честно, вообще сомневаюсь в том, что так легально делать, ведь программа должна быть конечной. А у меня, получается, программа "с многоточием". Но никаких других мыслей нет вообще.

Comment: В этом и суть написания алгоритмов, пока учишся, чтоб мозги начали мыслить алгоритмически. Если же переписывать готовые алгоритмы, толку на выходе будет мало. Начните хотя бы, добавьте код со своими попытками реализации и если уже что-то не выходит задайте вопрос и поясните что именно не выходит и как вы видите потенциальное решение. В таком варианте, вопрос выглядит так: "Сделайте за меня" :(

Comment: Напиши что сделал сам и что не работает/не получается. иначе закроют твой вопрос и вообще никогда не узнаешь правильного подхода

Comment: Прошу прощения, первый раз задавал вопрос на этом форуме. Исправился.